# Logstash: wrong sequence of fields in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have such a logstash config:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => '5044'
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ['./patterns']
        match => { 'message' => '%{TIME:timestamp}(","Event\s)(?<Event>([^"]+))(","Form\s)?(?<Form>([^"]+))?(","ParentType\s)?(?<parent_type>([^"]+))?(","ParentName\s)?(?<parent_name>([^"]+))?(","Type\s)?(?<type>([^"]+))?(","Name\s)?(?<Name_of_form>([^"]+))?(","Detail\s)?(?<Detail>([^"]+))?(","t=)?(?<t>([\d]+))?(",")?(?<Status>(end|beg))?' }
        add_tag => [ '%{Status}' ]
    }
    dissect {
        mapping => {
            '[log][file][path]' => 'C:\Logs\%{login}\%{server}\%{user}\%{filename}.txt'
        }
    }
    date {
        match => [ 'timestamp', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss' ]
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { 'uniqueEvent' => '%{Event}_%{filename}' }
    }
    elapsed {
        unique_id_field => 'uniqueEvent'
        start_tag => 'beg' 
        end_tag => 'end'
        new_event_on_match => false
    }

    if 'elapsed' in [tags] {
        aggregate {
            task_id => '%{uniqueEvent}'
            code => 'map["duration"] = [(event.get("elapsed_time")*1000).to_i]'
            map_action => 'create'
        }
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => ['timestamp', 'ecs', 'log', 'tags', 'message', '@version', 'filename', 'input', 'host', 'agent', 't', 'parent_type', 'parent_name', 'type']
        rename => {'elapsed_time' => 'Event_duration'}
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ['localhost:9200']
        index => 'logs-%{+dd.MM.YYYY}'
    }
}
```

In elasticsearch, the fields I need are always displayed in a different sequence and this is a little infuriating. I only have a few text fields, two date fields and one number field. Elasticsearch itself perfectly defines the type, but I would like all the data to be in strict sequence in each index. Can this be done?

The mapping should be in such a strict sequence:

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "Event": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Form": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Name_of_form": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Detail": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Event_duration": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "elapsed_timestamp_start": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "user": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "login": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "server": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Status": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "uniqueEvent": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to implement this according to the first and only guide on [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash_lesson_elasticsearch_mapping) topic, but nothing worked. According to the articles of other people, I created template.json in the logstash directory, but when launched this template did not work, the error was of the type: this template is not in elasticsearch.

How do I create this file correctly? How to write it correctly to the input block? Will this all work?

Thanks for any help!

The error is still like this:

```
[2020-08-25T19:33:13,365][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using mapping template from {:path=>"C:\\Users\\moral\\elk_stack\\logstash-7.8.1\\template\\template.json"}
[2020-08-25T19:33:13,406][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logs-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "Event"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "Form"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "Name_of_form"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "Detail"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "Event_duration"=>{"type"=>"float"}, "elapsed_timestamp_start"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "user"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "login"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "server"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "Status"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}, "uniqueEvent"=>{"type"=>"text", "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}}}}
[2020-08-25T19:33:13,421][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/log-template
[2020-08-25T19:33:13,468][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Failed to install template. {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://localhost:9200/_template/log-template'", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError", :backtrace=>["C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:80:in `perform_request'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:332:in `perform_request_to_url'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:319:in `block in perform_request'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:414:in `with_connection'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:318:in `perform_request'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:326:in `block in Pool'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:352:in `template_put'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:86:in `template_install'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:28:in `install'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:16:in `install_template'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:205:in `install_template'", "C:/Users/moral/elk_stack/logstash-7.8.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.5.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:49:in `block in setup_after_successful_connection'"]}
```

template.json file:

```
{
  "template" : "logs-*",
  "version" : 50001,
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "Event": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "Form": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "Name_of_form": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "Detail": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "Event_duration": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "elapsed_timestamp_start": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "user": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "login": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "server": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "Status": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "uniqueEvent": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is simply tell Logstash to install the template upon starting. Just make sure that the `index_patterns` in your template matches your index name (i.e. `logs-*`)

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ['localhost:9200']
        index => 'logs-%{+dd.MM.YYYY}'

        manage_template => true
        template_overwrite => true
        template_name => "log-template"
        template => "/path/to/template.json"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't work out. Added error text. Maybe I need to add it to elasticsearch manually before running logstash?

Comment: Error 400... Can you also add your template.json file to your question, something must be wrong in it

Comment: Added template.json. From what might help: elasticsearch works, but it's completely empty.

Comment: Remove `_default_` (it's deprecated) and everything will shine ;-)

Comment: `[logs-03.08.2020] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [log-template], shards [1]/[1], mappings [_doc]` 
Now there is no error, but when displayed in Postman, the fields are still in a different order :( 
Why do we even need to specify this template?

Comment: What do you mean by order exactly? The _source document you see will be exactly as Logstash sends it to ES, ES will never modify it. Also the JSON specification doesn't mention any ordering of the keys, a JSON document is a hashmap and there's inherently no key order

Comment: I am passing several log time fields, several action fields and several user information fields to elasticsearch. I meant that everything in _source is in a different order (time, form, event_time, user, form name, more time, more information about the user, etc.), and I wanted everything to be in order: first information about time -> then about action -> about the user. And I thought that setting up mapping in logstash would solve this problem, but now it seems I realized that I was wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, there is no such thing as field order in JSON documents. Glad you figured it out